# Uncertainty in a theorem about Sarrus numbers

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes, oeis

From https://oeis.org/A001567 there is a theorem of Ray Chandler formulated:

> An odd composite number $2n + 1$ is in the sequence if and only if
>   multiplicative order of $2\;(\text{mod}(2n+1))$ divides $2n$.

I suppose that "in the sequence" refers to the sequence of pseudoprimes, composites $n$ such that $n|2^{n-1}-1$, but I don't understand the formulation of this theorem. Is it a typo in the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you miscopied the text in your question. It actually says that:

An odd composite number $2n + 1$ is in the sequence if and only if multiplicative order of $2 \pmod{(2n+1)}$ divides $2n$.

So Chandler's theorem states that, if $2^k \equiv 1 \pmod{(2n+1)}$, then $k | 2n$.

Comment: I didn't understand the original text either but didn't notice the miscopy. But I do understand your explanation. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, this isn't a theorem so much as it is a comment by Chandler.  If $k$ is the order of $2$ mod $2n+1$, then by definition (or elementary properties) $2^m \equiv 1$ iff $k \mid m$.  in particular, $2^{2n} \equiv 1$ iff $k\mid 2n$; it's just plugging in the most basic property of orders into the definition of pseudoprime.  Your restatement doesn't seem to capture this.